# Have some problems with my revalidate/repaint

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, refresh, panel

i tried to fix it with `revalidate()` & `repaint()` but it didn't work out for me, i searched for some more solutions, but everytime i try it doesn't work for me, could anyone help me please?
thanks alot,

Here is my script (not full)

```
 public JPanel createPanel() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
 {
      FormLayout formlayout1 = new 

    FormLayout("FILL:DEFAULT:NONE,FILL:119PX:NONE,
    FILL:30PX:NONE,FILL:24PX:NONE,FILL:130PX:NONE,
    FILL:16PX:NONE","CENTER:DEFAULT:NONE,CENTER:30PX:NONE,
    CENTER:30PX:NONE,CENTER:25PX:NONE,CENTER:25PX:NONE,
    CENTER:25PX:NONE,CENTER:25PX:NONE,CENTER:25PX:NONE");

          CellConstraints cc = new CellConstraints();
          jpanel1.setLayout(formlayout1);

          JLabel lbl = null;
          JTextArea col = null;
          int i = 3;

         for (OverzichtVo o : OverzichtBusiness.getOverzicht()){
         lbl = new JLabel(mapServices.get(o.getServiceid()));
         jpanel1.add(lbl, cc.xy(2, i));
         col = new JTextArea();
         col.setEditable(false);
         LineBorder lineborder1 = new LineBorder(new Color(0,0,0),2,false);
         col.setBorder(lineborder1);
         col.setBackground(colors[o.getStatusid()-1]);        
         jpanel1.add(col, cc.xy(3, i));
         lbl = new JLabel(o.getExtrainfo());
         jpanel1.add(lbl, cc.xy(5, i));
         i++;

      button.setFont(new Font("Poor Richard",Font.PLAIN,20));
      button.setName("button");
      LineBorder lnbord = new LineBorder(new Color(0,0,0),2,false);
      button.setBorder(lnbord);
      refresh();
      jpanel1.add(button,cc.xy(5,2));

      m_lbloverzicht.setFont(new Font("Poor Richard",Font.PLAIN,30));
      m_lbloverzicht.setName("lbloverzicht");
      m_lbloverzicht.setText("Overzicht");
      LineBorder lineborder1 = new LineBorder(new Color(0,0,0),2,false);
      m_lbloverzicht.setBorder(lineborder1);
      jpanel1.add(m_lbloverzicht,cc.xy(2,2));

      addFillComponents(jpanel1,new int[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 },new int[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 });
      return jpanel1;
 }
 private void refresh(){
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            jpanel1.revalidate();
         jpanel1.repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

and i activate it all in another class :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    AlgemeneFrm frm_alg = new AlgemeneFrm();
    frame.add(frm_alg);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    frame.setSize(350,250); 
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to refresh my whole Jpanel/panel cause my Jtextarea(background) is green, when i change something it's suppose to go red. that works fine for me if i stop application and start it again, but i added a button, so i could refresh/update my application or just panel. but it won't work with my 'refresh' button within 'panelname'.revalidate();and 'panelname'.repaint();
help please

Comment: What is the problem you are having, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm trying to refresh my whole panel cause my textarea(background) is green when i change something it's suppose to go red. it works fine for me if i stop application and start again, but i added a button, so i could refresh my panel. but it won't work with my refresh() button. so i don't have to restart my whole application.
thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Quit shouting! Bold is used to highlight a few key words, not the entire question.